# Similar posts formatting

Tags: list

I'm using the similar posts plugin `http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/similar-posts/`, and I want the similar posts to show on the same line instead of as a list...

like
link 1, link 2, link 3, link 4

instead of
link 1
link 2
link 3
link 4

I posted this on the wordpress forum and on the plugin's official site days ago and still no answer... please help me!

(I know very little about coding, so try to be specific, and if you give me code explain what each line does so I can learn please)

thanks!

Added info:
I'm using mostly default settings for the plugin, I think the only change I made was to set it to only consider tags.  I would think there would be something I could change on the output settings tab, but I have no idea what.  I've got it set to display after the content because I couldn't figure out what file to put `<?php similar_posts(); ?>` and that's really where I wanted it anyways so it worked out perfectly.
Oh, I am using the default theme Twenty Ten.

Follow the link to wordpress forums in my chosen answer below for the missing parts of the discussion.

Comment: I think you should add some more information to your question and check the formatting. And please link the plugin so it's clear which one you use. From what I see with the one on google place 1, there are many ways to customize this, so if you write about your configuration of the plugin, this might be much easier to answer and probably won't need any code-changes. So easier for you to understand and configure in the end as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that my post was displaying the list wrong.... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've responded to your thread on the WP forums, see here..
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/simple-question-about-similar-posts-plugin

You can do what you want from the plugin's settings page..

**EDIT:** Following the CSS suggestion, if you wanted to try this method.

1. Leave the fields as they were
2. Update the `<ul>` field to now read `<ul id="my_special_id">`
3. Update your theme's style.css file with the below.

Example CSS.

```
#my_special_id, 
#my_special_id li { display:inline; }
#my_special_id li a { margin-right: 5px; }
```

Which should result in the list items displaying side by side. The margin is to push the items away from one another, else they'll look like one long sting..

The `{link}` text is basically just a placeholder for output produced by the plugin, not much different to how a shortcode works...

Comment: Ahhh, I actually tried that and it just put a comma after each one without changing the way they were listed, although I can't remember if I cleared the other fields in the same attempt or at a different time, so I'll try again.... I tried everything I could think of, but like I said in my question I know next to nothing about coding (except vb) so I while I might understand the <li> and <ul> I don't know {link} and I can only learn so much in a few hours

Comment: ok, I followed your instructions exactly and it does like I said, leaves them in list format and just adds a comma after each one.  I thought I had tried everything obvious before I posted, and I guess I was right.  I left it like that so you could go see if you want.  http://www.top-iphone-apps.info/?p=55

could the group title template box on the output settings page help in this case?

or maybe somehow it has to do with the language and .po files my server doesn't allow (I doubt it, but maybe?)

Comment: There's now a list element `<ul>` present but no list items.. Can you provide a screenshot of the 3 fields? So i can compare how the output behaves with what you have in the fields..

Comment: Added an update to my response on the WordPress forum... ;)

Comment: Sigh..... why is this so difficult!  The css solution isn't working, but it's entirely possible that I'm an idiot and am not adding it to the right place in the css file?

Comment: I wish YARRP had worked

Comment: Posted additional response there, if you match the config i used it should work(because it did for me)...

Comment: ok I think I'm going to have to give up.... did you set it to display after the post or did you add the `<?php similar_posts(); ?>` somewhere? If you did add it, where does it go? If not I'm stuck because http://yfrog.com/e3similarpostsoptionsp and http://yfrog.com/bcsimilarpostsnotworkingp  If you didn't use the `<?php similar_posts(); ?>` is there anyplace in the style.css where I shouldn't put the code from your answer?  Of course you could check my page in case somehow my cache isn't clearing or one of my firefox plugins is messing it up. http://www.top-iphone-apps.info/?p=44.

Comment: Or it could be my free hosting if anyone on ulmb.com wants to try this (heck only like one popup every 30 min, 5gb space 500gb month bandwidth.... just can't upload certain types of files and no access to .htaccess or whatever it is, but it seems to me like it was a good deal)... if someone has an account there to try this and see if it's a problem with the host....

Comment: I added the similar_posts call inside single.php of the theme just after the post title(i wasn't being picky about placement because it was only a test), and it worked perfectly fine with that and only that(in addition to setting the config to how i've shown in the screenshot i posted - no css needed).

Comment: Ok I'll try adding the call and see if it works (thanks for telling me which file it goes in!!!)

Comment: ok that's better, removing display after post option and adding `<?php similar_posts(); ?>` actually seems to work - thank you for telling me where it goes.... now the question is, how do I add spaces in the options to put room between stuff... screenshot of my options page now that I'm ALMOST happy...  http://yfrog.com/bhsimilarpostsoptionsalmop  I assume there must be a code like `<br>` that's for spaces instead of lines

Comment: never mind... adding this to the end of my preceding text seemed to work `&nbsp;` although I'd be even happier if the comma was after the first link instead of before the second, but I can probably figure that out on my own

Comment: ok, changed the comma to a hyphen, added a space after it.... now I'm happy!!!!  http://www.top-iphone-apps.info/?p=44

Comment: Good to hear... :)

Answer (score 0):

chances are you could get it to display that way by altering the css properties for the code that the plugin spits out. particularly display: inline

Comment: I that.... but I don't know how or where... I guess I can go back to the w3schools site and try to figure it out a fifth time.